# Chisq.test not working in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test

I found out that the chi square test in R may not be working. I don't know where I am doing it wrong.

1) test two similar distribution

```
# create a sequence from 0 to 1000, seperated by 10
x <- seq(0,1000,10)

# create two similar gaussian distribution
r1<- rnorm(x, 1000,100)
r2 <- rnorm(x, 1000,100)

# run the chi square test
chisq.test(r1,r2,simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

The result is:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  r1 and r2
X-squared = 10100, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

2) Test two different distribution

```
# create two different gaussian distribution
r1<- rnorm(x, 500,100)
r2 <- rnorm(x, 1000,100)

# run the chi square test
chisq.test(r1,r2,simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

Result:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  r1 and r2
X-squared = 10100, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

This suggests that whether the distributions I tested are different or not, the chi sq test will say that they are not the same.

The result is the same whether of not `simulate.p.value` is `TRUE`.

Comment: The chi-square test is intended for categorical data, not continuous data.

Comment: @jbowman is correct.  This really ought to give an error. But the df = NA is a clue.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open because, while it is about R, the underlying problem is statistical - don't use chisquare test on continuous variables.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, the problem is that r1 and r2 is not categorical. ks.test(r1, r2) works out fine.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, that you are using `chisq.test` wrong.

```
chisq.test(x = r1, y = r2, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

Is not a test, if r1 and r2 stem from the same distribution. Instead, the manual says

> Otherwise, x and y must be vectors or factors of the same length; [...] the objects are coerced to factors, and the contingency table is computed from these. Then Pearson's chi-squared test is performed of the null hypothesis that the joint distribution of the cell counts in a 2-dimensional contingency table is the product of the row and column marginals.

You are basically producing a 100x100 contingency table consisting of mostly zeros and some ones.

So if I understand you right, you try to do a chisquare distribution test but asked R to do a chisquare test of independence.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! Yes, indeed I think I phrased it wrong, I was testing independence of two datasets r1, r2. I tried testing the distribution in this way: chisq.test(r1,p=dnorm(x, 1000,100),simulate.p.value = TRUE,rescale.p = TRUE). Unfortunately, it says Chi-squared test for given probabilities with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates), but p-value = 0.0004998

Comment: This time r1 <- rnorm(x, 1000,100), and I am comparing it against the distribution dnorm(x, 1000,100). I don't see why still p value is so low.

Comment: In `chisq.test(x = r1, p = ...)` where `r1` is not `integer` you produced a case, which is not even mentioned in `help(chisq.test)` where it says >" if x is a vector and y is not given, then a goodness-of-fit test is performed (x is treated as a one-dimensional contingency table). The entries of x must be non-negative integers." Mind that last sentence! All I can say  is that you will not learn R by random typing what you think should work but only by learning it's functions. Try https://www.r-bloggers.com/goodness-of-fit-test-in-r/ of google or bing or something. `fortune(348)`